# Adding content to the DOM: any limits?

Tags: html, ajax, dom

The question may be a bit theoretical (did I mean rhetorical?) or fuzzy, but here it is anyway.

I'm planning to build a web page where content will be added through Ajax requests and displayed using tabs and panes. The initial view has just one tab and shows a list of links. Clicking on a link opens a new tab/pane. The user can navigate through the tabs and close them, just like in a web browser.

I could build a UI able to display an unlimited number of tabs, but that implies adding DOM content to as many -- and possibly a lot of -- panes. More likely, I'll set a limit to how many tabs can be open simultaneously. But what should that limit be? What rule would you follow? What's your experience in how much content a DOM document can hold without impact on performance?

Comment: Since DOM document belongs to client browser the impact of performance varies with the client machine memory and processing power, so you cannot predict the exact number before impeding performance. I think you should keep it to minimum number of tabs.

Comment: Yes, that's way a said my question is a bit "fuzzy". It's rather about what do you feel is a safe limit in an average configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to answer your question. I, for example, have Chrome and Firefox running side by side right now. All browsers together need 9.85GB of shared memory (so some of that RAM is shared between all browsers; I have only 8GB of RAM and about 2GB is actually in use).

There is no JavaScript API to tell when memory gets tight; the only indication is that the machine is starting to swap or that the browser is crashing.

So you have the following solutions:

1. Limit the user to something that is too small. Good for you, bad for power users like me.
2. Set the limit too big. Bad for you, since users will start complaining how your stupid site makes their browser crash but good for me.
3. Instead of setting a limit, clear the panes which are not visible. Save the state of the pane somewhere (server, [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)) and restore it when the user opens it. Quite some effort but it would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. At least I understand you won't complain about my stupid site! PS: your link about local storage looks interesting.